# Delete multiple files from GitHub API

Tags: ruby, github-api

I'm trying to delete multiple files from a few subdirectories using octokit.rb - to be clear, what I’m really trying to do is just delete some subdirectories in their entirety. If there’s a better way to do that (in one commit) please point me in the right direction. I have a working example of this when CREATING the 'foo' directory, and its files, but DELETING the directory is giving me problems. Here's my code, using octokit:

```
client = Octokit::Client.new(...)
repo = 'dudo/k8s_colors'
namespace = 'foo'

ref = 'heads/master'
sha_latest_commit = client.ref(repo, ref).object.sha

sha_base_tree = client.commit(repo, sha_latest_commit).commit.tree.sha
base_tree = client.tree(repo, sha_base_tree, recursive: true)
clean_tree = base_tree.tree.select { |o| o.type == 'blob' && !o.path.include?("overlays/#{namespace}") }
                           .map { |o| o.to_h.slice(:path, :mode, :type, :sha) }
sha_new_tree = client.create_tree(repo, clean_tree).sha # TODO: this doesn't work
```

This call to `create_tree` doesn't produce the tree I'm expecting, though.

```
> base_tree

{:sha=>"2c89f29eab56c8f53bcbb5649bb326433e439629",
 :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/2c89f29eab56c8f53bcbb5649bb326433e439629",
 :tree=>
  [{:path=>".gitignore", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"f494b1b6ae2590ef5998845626566708ec9e2908", :size=>15, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/f494b1b6ae2590ef5998845626566708ec9e2908"},
   {:path=>"blue", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"ac10637c3435b466ef29ddc5c0f40f047f1b7e92", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/ac10637c3435b466ef29ddc5c0f40f047f1b7e92"},
   {:path=>"blue/base", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"4996aaefbf8099595515907a8e80dd266638afcc", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/4996aaefbf8099595515907a8e80dd266638afcc"},
   {:path=>"blue/base/deployment.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"770bdc76ea5a29ba7e5219cd9cedfa7333adb084", :size=>512, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/770bdc76ea5a29ba7e5219cd9cedfa7333adb084"},
   {:path=>"blue/base/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"f2e9e9babb19978ec3dc3e10e71a2b3cbd80840f", :size=>292, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/f2e9e9babb19978ec3dc3e10e71a2b3cbd80840f"},
   {:path=>"blue/base/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"80a9ccdb3a395395b58fa462b2b4d0339665862e", :size=>122, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/80a9ccdb3a395395b58fa462b2b4d0339665862e"},
   {:path=>"blue/overlays", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"34e882c2a2b76ef926bfe179aaba688e2956ff12", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/34e882c2a2b76ef926bfe179aaba688e2956ff12"},
   {:path=>"blue/overlays/foo", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"aa9a92503f622aa6d61c74a63dda655a3afe0bf8", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/aa9a92503f622aa6d61c74a63dda655a3afe0bf8"},
   {:path=>"blue/overlays/foo/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"2245b69ea811665de2bea620db394d69fe41f768", :size=>311, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/2245b69ea811665de2bea620db394d69fe41f768"},
   {:path=>"blue/overlays/foo/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"af1742cdd917b7207377874ba34263a782fce673", :size=>147, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/af1742cdd917b7207377874ba34263a782fce673"},
   {:path=>"red", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"a8442ac6ab5be147f5452aa4a94061b81b0dc32b", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/a8442ac6ab5be147f5452aa4a94061b81b0dc32b"},
   {:path=>"red/base", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"9374bbaec9f3ca88bfc4dcbdee421d8edecd9d73", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/9374bbaec9f3ca88bfc4dcbdee421d8edecd9d73"},
   {:path=>"red/base/deployment.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"3a8d2448475d851e851dff1fc36d1bb443c8acea", :size=>507, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/3a8d2448475d851e851dff1fc36d1bb443c8acea"},
   {:path=>"red/base/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"b9322cc79212813285b93467e15aa5aea08eb442", :size=>289, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/b9322cc79212813285b93467e15aa5aea08eb442"},
   {:path=>"red/base/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"5113689b6a1c1aca2b36a3c513d9c143e8ae12e0", :size=>120, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/5113689b6a1c1aca2b36a3c513d9c143e8ae12e0"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"a4f8d5b81643b26684f7db7af17bf5d2d95c3c1b", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/a4f8d5b81643b26684f7db7af17bf5d2d95c3c1b"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays/foo", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"bccf70cc1e84f1724116644ee8c82cf4ab734834", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/bccf70cc1e84f1724116644ee8c82cf4ab734834"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays/foo/deployment.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"3e050646dd49721b3d701929c0a89db831ebea14", :size=>524, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/3e050646dd49721b3d701929c0a89db831ebea14"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays/foo/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"840d45bb3c5c6c81a1ac71d82ee49d348653ffc7", :size=>308, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/840d45bb3c5c6c81a1ac71d82ee49d348653ffc7"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays/foo/namespace.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"9eb7d29d67093ec524dcea1b32f3eeb7c2cecc81", :size=>57, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/9eb7d29d67093ec524dcea1b32f3eeb7c2cecc81"},
   {:path=>"red/overlays/foo/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"43d2053a6f237d643036499fa7b01d7b01fc2111", :size=>142, :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/blobs/43d2053a6f237d643036499fa7b01d7b01fc2111"}],
 :truncated=>false}


> clean_tree

[
  {:path=>".gitignore", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"f494b1b6ae2590ef5998845626566708ec9e2908"}, 
  {:path=>"blue/base/deployment.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"770bdc76ea5a29ba7e5219cd9cedfa7333adb084"}, 
  {:path=>"blue/base/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"f2e9e9babb19978ec3dc3e10e71a2b3cbd80840f"}, 
  {:path=>"blue/base/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"80a9ccdb3a395395b58fa462b2b4d0339665862e"}, 
  {:path=>"red/base/deployment.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"3a8d2448475d851e851dff1fc36d1bb443c8acea"}, 
  {:path=>"red/base/ingress.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"b9322cc79212813285b93467e15aa5aea08eb442"}, 
  {:path=>"red/base/service.yaml", :mode=>"100644", :type=>"blob", :sha=>"5113689b6a1c1aca2b36a3c513d9c143e8ae12e0"}
]


> client.create_tree(repo, clean_tree)

{:sha=>"2a8800e18b5a4dc50414fc380e2d2d66401082d3",
 :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/2a8800e18b5a4dc50414fc380e2d2d66401082d3",
 :tree=>
  [{:path=>"blue", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"d0554827144fae7e578edb545d07e8e43bd17b74", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/d0554827144fae7e578edb545d07e8e43bd17b74"},
   {:path=>"red", :mode=>"040000", :type=>"tree", :sha=>"f2d7ff860c04b80fb4f9b6cba5304d0ca0a6816f", :url=>"https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/f2d7ff860c04b80fb4f9b6cba5304d0ca0a6816f"}],
 :truncated=>false}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) You get the `sha` from the last [`commit`](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Commits.html#commit-instance_method) from the repo

```
sha_base_tree = client.commit(repo, sha_latest_commit).commit.tree.sha
```

2) You fetch all the [`tree` objects](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Objects.html#tree-instance_method)

```
base_tree = client.tree(repo, sha_base_tree, recursive: true)
```

3) You loop and modify those `threes`.

```
cleaned_tree = base_tree.tree.reject { |blob| blob.path.include? ['overlays', namespace].join('/') }
sanitized_tree = cleaned_tree.map { |o| o.to_h.slice(:path, :mode, :type, :sha) }
sha_new_tree = client.create_tree(repo, sanitized_tree)
```

4) You need to incude **the correct path to the repo `dudo/k8s_colors`** in [`create_tree(repo, sanitized_tree)`](http://octokit.github.io/octokit.rb/Octokit/Client/Objects.html#create_tree-instance_method)

```
client.create_tree('dudo/k8s_colors', sanitized_tree)
```

I tried to retrieve your tree via [github api get request](https://developer.github.com/v3/git/trees/#get-a-tree). The [request returns `not found`](https://api.github.com/repos/dudo/k8s_colors/git/trees/2a8800e18b5a4dc50414fc380e2d2d66401082d3), which means you did not create any tree. The repo does not exist even [on your github repository](https://github.com/dudo?utf8=%E2%9C%93&tab=repositories&q=&type=&language=).

also `.create_tree` returns the following `head` commits.

1. `2a8800e18b5a4dc50414fc380e2d2d66401082d3`
2. blue `d0554827144fae7e578edb545d07e8e43bd17b74`
3. red `f2d7ff860c04b80fb4f9b6cba5304d0ca0a6816f`

To help further we need to see all the trees on github, those from base and those originating sanitized tree and review those commits. I would verify in the history that those commits do not exist.

Comment: The `sanitized_tree` params that I'm passing are represented in the last code snippet, which also explains the text in question. The sanitized_tree looks good, but upon creating the new tree, the trees and blobs I would expect to be there still, are gone.

Comment: I updated my question with the `sanitized_tree` to show what I mean.

Comment: @Dudo I updated my answer, I believe you are using the wrong path to the repo as by point 4)

Comment: typo on my part (in the question, since that variable is passed in via `ruby feature_cleanup.rb -n foo -r dudo/k8s_colors`). Also, the repo is private. Updated question to show `base_tree`.

Comment: I also renamed a variable. I only have `clean_tree` now.

Comment: @Dudo currently I don't have any idea, but later I will check again. The only thing I notice is that `create_tree` returns new commits. I wonder what actually is included in that tree. Only sha `d0554827144fae7e578edb545d07e8e43bd17b74` and `f2d7ff860c04b80fb4f9b6cba5304d0ca0a6816f` ? What does those commits include? are they merge commits including all the commits from `base_tree`?